# Is it possible to restrict Rhiny SliderInput's intervals while traversing a wider interval?

Tags: r, shiny, time-series, shinydashboard

This may have already been answered, but I don't know if it is in the context of date time.

Right now, I have a slider input shown here:

```
                 sliderInput(
                   "timeRange", label = "Choose Time Range:",
                   min = as.POSIXct("2020-12-01 00:00:00"),
                   max = as.POSIXct("2020-12-31 23:59:59"),
                   value = c(as.POSIXct("2020-12-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-01 01:00:00")),
                   timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", ticks = T, dragRange = FALSE, step=2000, animate = T
                 )
```

Now I could have restricted the min and max to an hourly time interval, however that means that my slider will only show the times between `2020-12-01 00:00:00` and  `2020-12-01 01:00:00`.

I would like the values to be fixed so that if I drag the slider, the slider with its intervals will also move but at the same time, stay within the same interval between `2020-12-01 00:00:00` and `2020-12-31 23:59:59`shown like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/502BN.png). (note that the time on the image is 6 minutes ahead, I am fine with that as that there is not exact full hour in the dataset I am working with.

Is this even possible to do with `sliderInput()`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I had a fellow co-worker answered my question. Apparently you need to subtract an hour from the maximum

```
                     max = as.POSIXct("2020-12-31 23:59:59") - hours(1),
                     value = as.POSIXct("2020-12-15 17:00:00"),
                     timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", ticks = T, step=3600, animate = T
```